# How to get class predictions from a trained Tensorflow classifier?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have have trained binary classifier model. The model class contains `self.cost`, `self.initial_state`, `self.final_state` and `self.logits` params. It is saved simply with `tf.train.Saver`:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables(), max_to_keep=1)
saver.save(session, 'model.ckpt')
```

After the model was trained I load it as:

```
with tf.variable_scope("Model", reuse=False):
    model = MODEL(config, is_training=False)

with tf.Session() as session:
    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
    saver.restore(session, 'model.ckpt')
```

However, my `model.run` function returns cross-entropy loss which is the last op in the graph. I don't need loss, I need the model predictions for each batch element

```
logits = tf.sigmoid(tf.nn.xw_plus_b(last_layer, self.output_w, self.output_b))
```

where `last_layer` is a `800x1` matrix which I then later reshape into `32x25x1` (batch_size, sequence_length, 1) matrix. It is this matrix that contains the model prediction values in [0-1] range.

So, how can I use this model to make a prediction for single element matrix `1x1x1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the OPs necessary to compute accuracy, something like what I have copied below (simply copied out of the closest model I had at hand).

```
  self.logits_flat = tf.argmax(logits, axis=1, output_type=tf.int32)
  labels_flat = tf.argmax(labels, axis=1, output_type=tf.int32)
  accuracy = tf.cast(tf.equal(self.logits_flat, labels_flat), tf.float32, name='accuracy')
```

Now when you run the model (either during test or training time) add accuracy to the sess.run call as:

```
sess.run([train_op, accuracy], feed_dict=...)
```

or

```
sess.run([accuracy, logits], feed_dict=...)
```

All you're doing when you call `sess.run` is to tell tensorflow to compute the value of whatever you ask for. You need to pass it in any data it needs to perform those computations. Tensorflow is lazy, it won't perform any computations that aren't explicitly necessary to produce the results you request. E.g. if you run the second version of `sess.run` listed above the optimizer will not be run and hence your weights will not be updated.

Note that you can add the OPs after the network was trained because none of them actually add any variables so they won't affect the save/restore process any.

Comment: I see. What if I don't need to compute the accuracy but just need a prediction score per single input label? Would `session.run({"logits": self.logits}, feed_dict)` work or do I have to pass `train_op` to enable sequential dependency?

Comment: Exactly correct. The magic of tensorflow will figure out the minimum necessary dependencies that it needs to compute `logits` in this case and return it. In fact you must not request `train_op`, if you do it will update your weights, not what you intended. Notice how you can use the same graph, same session even, to perform inference after training has completed by simply changing what OPs you request from `sess.run`.

Comment: Also notice that if you request just `logits`, you don't need to pass in the `labels` placeholder because that's not part of computing only `logits`, but it would be part of computing `accuracy` if you requested that.